# Discord.py MissingRequiredArgument: url is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

```py
import youtube_dl

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self , client):
        self.client = client
    

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx ,url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':'bestaudio', 'default-search': "ytdlsearch"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client
        
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['format'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFPEG_OPTIONS)
            
            vc.play(source)

    def setup(client):
         client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask questions here. Where's your problem? What's the traceback? What are you trying to do? Please provide more context with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based off the error in the title, you aren't putting the url in the command when running it. I also noticed some other things, like you didn't import discord, you have a bot declaration in a cog, and you are using `discord.Intents.all()`, which isn't recommended (unless your bot uses every privileged intent, which it *probably* doesn't). This can lead to difficulty in getting your bot verified.